# What is the Google App Engine equivalent of Android's 'Application' class? for dependency injection

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dagger-2

Android lets us extend `Application`, which is a great place to store our singletons so they can be easily reused throughout different pages (actiivities) in the app.

What is Google App-Engine's equivalent of this?

I am using dagger, and I don't want to create a new object graph for every endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (although I'm by no means sure it's the best) is just to self-inject your Cloud Endpoints class (through static field injection).

Presumably you're initialising the object graph in a ServletContextListener so you could do so there, before your endpoint methods are called.

Dagger 1.x supports staticInjections on the module annotation (to do that for you) but this is apparently no longer supported in 2.x.

Comment: Using dagger 2 unfortunately

Comment: Then you can just manually self-inject after you've initialized your object graph.

Comment: Here's my issue. Let's say I create my Singleton `component` in my `ServletContextListener`. Now I'm in my endpoint class. How do I get a reference to that `component` object? In Android, I would just call `getApplication()` from my `activity`. Endpoints don't extend a class, so I don't see any `getServletContext()` methods that I can use.

Comment: Oh wait I could just make the `component` a static Singleton in my `ServletContextListener`

Comment: ...or put a static field in your endpoint class and set it from ServletContextListener where you have the object graph.  Then your endpoint class doesn't need to know about ServletContextListener.